# What does zsh's typeset -t do?

Tags: zsh

In the zsh [docs for the typeset command](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html):

> -t
> Tags the named parameters. Tags have no special meaning to the shell. This flag has a different meaning when used with -f; see above

What does tagging a parameter do? Where is this tag used?

Comment: Only reference I've found to `typeset -t` on the `zsh` mailing list so far: https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2023/msg00219.html

Comment: Questions about ZSH are on-topic. If anyone wants to debate this specific question, please start a post on Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$foo` has been tagged, then:

- `typeset -p foo` will show the `-t` flag in `$foo`'s declaration.
- `${(t)foo}` and `$parameters[foo]` will include `-tag` as part of `$foo`'s type.

Additionally, you can use `typeset -pt` (without arguments) to get a list of all tagged parameters.

For example:

```bash
% foo=bar
% typeset -p foo          # show declaration
typeset foo=bar
% typeset -pt             # show all tagged
% print ${(t)foo}         # show type
scalar
% print $parameters[foo]  # show type
scalar
% typeset -t foo          # add tag
% typeset -p foo          # show declaration
typeset -t foo=bar
% typeset -pt             # show all tagged
typeset -t foo=bar
% print ${(t)foo}         # show type
scalar-tag
% print $parameters[foo]  # show type
scalar-tag
% typeset +t foo          # remove tag
```

As far as I know, and in agreement with the comment that "tags have no special meaning to the shell", that's *all* it does. It's just a boolean flag associated with a parameter, with the same lifetime as the parameter, that you can set and unset, and later check for.

Answer (score 1):

Adjunct to @hobb's great answer,

Despite the "different meaning" called out by the docs, it looks like under the hood the "other", function-specific use with `typeset -f -t` uses the same [PM_TAGGED param type](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/builtin.c#l3348) for both the param and function cases. It is defined [here where typeset's other param type flags are defined](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/params.c#l5897):

```
struct paramtypes {
    int binflag;    /* The relevant PM_FLAG(S) */
    const char *string; /* String for verbose output */
    int typeflag;   /* Flag for typeset -? */
    int flags;      /* The enum above */
};

static const struct paramtypes pmtypes[] = {
    { PM_AUTOLOAD, "undefined", 0, 0},
    { PM_INTEGER, "integer", 'i', PMTF_USE_BASE},
    { PM_EFLOAT, "float", 'E', 0},
    { PM_FFLOAT, "float", 'F', 0},
    { PM_ARRAY, "array", 'a', 0},
    { PM_HASHED, "association", 'A', 0},
    { 0, "local", 0, PMTF_TEST_LEVEL},
    { PM_LEFT, "left justified", 'L', PMTF_USE_WIDTH},
    { PM_RIGHT_B, "right justified", 'R', PMTF_USE_WIDTH},
    { PM_RIGHT_Z, "zero filled", 'Z', PMTF_USE_WIDTH},
    { PM_LOWER, "lowercase", 'l', 0},
    { PM_UPPER, "uppercase", 'u', 0},
    { PM_READONLY, "readonly", 'r', 0},
    { PM_TAGGED, "tagged", 't', 0},         <-----------
    { PM_EXPORTED, "exported", 'x', 0},
    { PM_UNIQUE, "unique", 'U', 0},
    { PM_TIED, "tied", 'T', 0},
    { PM_NAMEREF, "nameref", 'n', 0}
};
```

There are several uses of it to check if functions are marked for tracing. Just a guess, but perhaps it was originally added for the function case as a way to mark functions for tracing [like you see here in this shell function exec function](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/exec.c#l5906):

```
if (flags & (PM_TAGGED|PM_TAGGED_LOCAL))
    opts[XTRACE] = 1;
else if (oflags & PM_TAGGED_LOCAL) {
    if (shfunc->node.nam == ANONYMOUS_FUNCTION_NAME /* pointer comparison */)
    flags |= PM_TAGGED_LOCAL;
    else
    opts[XTRACE] = 0;
}
```

So, maybe the param boolean is just a weird artifact of how it was implemented for the function case.